# Drawing a 3D plot of a lower half of a torus

Tags: 3d, tikz-3dplot

As the title suggests, I would like a 3D plot of a lower half of a hollow torus with small radius 1 and large radius 2. I found an image online that resembles what I am looking for.

[image]

Could anyone find a simple way to recreate the above image, including the downward pointing blue arrow and labelled axes drawn on?

Comment: You've tagged the post with `tikz-3dplot`, have you tried that package? You should include some code for us to build off of (even just drawing the axes), rather than just asking for us to do the whole thing.

Comment: I have no experience with the packages, or otherwise I would include a code.

Comment: I could perhaps learn from other codes, but I don't understand how to get a half torus, i.e. all the examples I've seen so far are of a full torus, and I cannot seem to figure out how to limit the z range of the plot to z < 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I present an `asymptote` example because this yields the arguably nicer output. However, the parametrization of the half-torus can be used for other packages as well.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
 \begin{document}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{asy}
  size(200);
  import graph3;

  currentprojection=perspective(5,6,3);
  real R=4;
  real a=1;

  triple fs(pair t) {
    return ((R+a*Cos(t.y))*Cos(t.x),(R+a*Cos(t.y))*Sin(t.x),a*Sin(t.y));
  };

  surface s=surface(fs,(0,180),(360,360),8,8,Spline);
  draw(s,surfacepen=material(green+opacity(0.6), emissivepen=0.2*white),render(compression=Low,merge=true));

  xaxis3(Label("$x$",1),xmin=0,xmax=7,Arrow3);
  yaxis3(Label("$y$",1),ymin=0,ymax=7,Arrow3);
  zaxis3(Label("$z$",1),zmin=0,zmax=4,Arrow3);

  draw((4/sqrt(2),4/sqrt(2),-1)--(4/sqrt(2),4/sqrt(2),-4),blue,Arrow3);
 \end{asy}
 \end{document}
```

Of course, one needs to run `asy` between two compilations.

[image]

It is *possible* to draw similar picture with `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        axis equal,
        domain=0:360,
        y domain=180:360,
         ticks=none,
        view={130}{-35}
    ]

        \addplot3 [surf, color=green, opacity=0.1,faceted
        color=green!50!black,fill opacity=0.5%,faceted color=blue,z buffer=sort
        ]({(4+cos(y))*cos(x)},{(4+cos(y))*sin(x)},{sin(y)-0.01});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the outcome is, arguably, less appealing. Of course, with additional effort one may improve this. On the other hand, the nice thing about `asymptote` is that there this additional effort is not necessary.

Comment: I was wondering, is this also possible in tikz 3d plot?

Comment: @wrb98 It is certainly *possible*. I added an example to my answer. However, I feel that it is far less straightforward to achieve satisfying results with `pgfplots`, but this is of course just my personal taste. I am sure that a real `pgfplots` expert can improve the quality of the result.

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible to (in `pgfplots` ) draw the positive vertical axis over the surface? It is under (see the arrow tip).

Comment: @Sigur : I agree that it's odd. I tried to improve the outcome by shifting the half-torus by -0.01 in z-direction, with very limited success. But I am no `pgfplots` expert. I'm just a marmot. ;-)

Comment: For the `asymptote` version, I assume one has to use the usual three steps of first running `latex` on the file, then running `asy` on the generated `.asy` file, and finally run `latex` again. But on the initial `latex` command, I get an `Undefined control sequence` error: 
` l.13 \ASYalign
              (-174.145695,81.289005)(-0.500000,-0.500000){\hbox to 0pt{\inc...`.

Comment: @murray : run `pdflatex`, then `asy` and then `pdflatex`. As you say, `latex` does not work.